# Saving array in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store an array in `chrome.storage`. Here are my setter and getter functions:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({favs: []}, function(items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("retrieving data"+items);
        favs = items.favs;
        console.log("isarray:"+ favs instanceof Array);
    }
});
chrome.storage.local.set({ favs : favs }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("Runtime error.");
    } else{
        console.log("storing data")
    }
});
```

But the line `console.log("isarray:"+ favs instanceof Array);` returns false. Please tell where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `favs instanceof Array` with parenthesis like this: `(favs instanceof Array)` so your code will look like:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({favs: []}, function(items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("retrieving data"+items);
        favs = items.favs;
        // (wrap with parenthesis)
        console.log("isarray:" + (favs instanceof Array) );
    }
});
...
```

If you don't wrap that piece in parenthesis, javascript tries to evaluate if `"isarray:" + favs` is an instance of an `Array`, which it clearly isn't (string + array = string).